# One or two digit Hex converted to decimal display

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program in C# that prompts a user to enter a maximum two digit hexadecimal number and my program should convert the number to a decimal and display the result.  I have found too many help sites the help convert numbers as int to hex but not going the other way.  Anyone with ideas and advice?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Call `int.Parse("abc", NumberStyles.HexNumber)`.